# Can't access price of a Product in Django-Oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

Trying to access the price of a product, Using [Docs](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/prices_and_availability.html#prices-and-availability). But getting Attribute error.

```
>>> from oscar.apps.partner import strategy, prices
>>> from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
>>> product = Product.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> info = strategy.fetch_for_product(product)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fetch_for_product'
```

To see all attributes of strategy I do

```
  >>> dir(strategy)
  >>> ['Base', 'D', 'Default', 'DeferredTax', 'FixedRateTax', 'NoTax', 'PurchaseInfo', 
    'Selector', 'StockRequired', 'Structured', 'UK', 'US', 'UseFirstStockRecord', 
'__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',
 '__package__', 'availability', 'namedtuple', 'prices']
```

So fetch_for_product is not in attributes of strategy. Now how can I access the price of a particular product?

Comment: does strategy even has that method

Comment: Look at the docs, that's how they mention

Comment: compare your strategy with http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/oscar/apps/partner/strategy.html#Base.fetch_for_parent

Comment: Do I have to change something in Oscar before I can do this ? I m using the latest version of Django-Oscar. I didn't touch any model

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you import above is the strategy **module**. What you want is the strategy **object** instead. The easiest way to obtain the strategy is to ask the strategy **selector** for one:

```
from oscar.apps.partner.strategy import Selector

selector = Selector()
strategy = selector.strategy(request=..., user=...)
purchase_info = strategy.fetch_for_product(product=...)
price = purchase_info.price
```

The selector is useful as it allows you to use different strategies depending on the context (a particular user, request coming from a particular country etc.). In your own store you would override the `Selector` with your own implementation, by default it will return the [`Default` strategy](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/prices_and_availability.html#default-strategy).

See [the docs](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/prices_and_availability.html#loading-a-strategy) for more information.

Comment: This works. Whats the difference between strategy and selector ? Can you point me to the docs ?

Comment: is there anything you'd like me to add to the answer before you can accept it?

Comment: added a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984175/filtering-objects-in-a-view-in-django-oscar can you please answer.

Comment: need your help for this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986376/store-credit-virtual-currency-app-for-django-oscar

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new serializer with custom field to load the category product with price, primary image and title using [SerializeMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from oscar.apps.partner.strategy import Selector

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    availability = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields= ('id', 'title','availability', 'images', 'price',)

    def get_price(self, obj):
        strategy = Selector().strategy()
        price = vars(strategy.fetch_for_product(obj).price)
        price['final'] = price['excl_tax'] + price['tax']
        return price

    def get_availability(self, obj):
        strategy = Selector().strategy()
        availability = vars(strategy.fetch_for_product(obj).availability)
        try:
            return availability['num_available']
        except KeyError:
            return -1

    def get_images(self, obj):
        try:
            return ['https://127.0.0.1:8000/'+str(obj.primary_image().original)]
        except AttributeError:
            return []
```