# Filtering Objects in a View in Django - Oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

Trying to implement a simple ordering query on [ProductCategoryView](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/_modules/oscar/apps/catalogue/views.html#ProductCategoryView) in Django-Oscar. It should be fairly simple to implement but it's taking too much time to understand. I'm having second thoughts to go forward with Oscar or not as it seems difficult to extend.

The [ProductCategoryView](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/_modules/oscar/apps/catalogue/views.html#ProductCategoryView) returns products of a certain category. I want to sort them according to certain field in product model say `price`. First I change the parent generic class from `TemplateView` to `ListView` so that I can use `get_queryset` method. Then I override the `get_queryset` method as below and write a simple queryset in that. Still the sorting doesn't happen **though the flow does go inside the `get_queryset` method.**

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(categories = self.category)
        logger.debug("inside")
        queryset = queryset.order_by("price")           
        return queryset
```

So what methods I have to overwrite. Will there be so much trouble editing Oscar every time or I'm missing something?

P.S : I have asked lot of questions around Django/Oscar Class based view recently . So I might look like a [Help Vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). Please ignore this question if that is the case.

Comment: I think you are better off making this change by customising the appropriate class in catalogue `search_handlers` (e.g. `SimpleProductSearchHandler`) ...I think the fact that you have to make drastic changes to the view is a sign that it's the wrong place to try and make this change. I have found Oscar well designed and highly extensible, but unfortunately the docs are completely lacking in pointing you the right direction for a lot of things

Comment: Thanks, brief respite. Will try and get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Anentropic is right but let me elaborate a bit.

Oscar bases all its browse views on search engines so faceting can be used to narrow down the list of products returned. By default there are search engine integrations for [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).

If you don't use Solr or Elasticsearch, the default implementation is `SimpleProductSearchHandler`. It does not use any external services but instead [calls `Product.browsable.get_queryset()`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/releases/1.1/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/search_handlers.py#L101-L105). That code lives in [`oscar.apps.catalogue.managers`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/releases/1.1/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/managers.py#L44-L52) and could be customized to provide custom ordering.

This is all assuming you don't want to use a search engine as customizations required to change the order of results for other search handler classes are backend-specific.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. I added my `order_by` clause in `SimpleProductSearchHandler ` and it worked. I think things will get easy once I get the hang of Oscar.  Can you point me to some blog or doc that explain details of Oscar better than official docs ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only knowledge I have comes from first hand experience.