# Store Credit / Virtual Currency app for Django Oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I want to have a store credit model for customers where the virtual currency is stored. This store credit app will store points(added on return or some scheme) that can be used to pay for products.  Is [django-oscar-accounts](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-accounts) the right app for that ? Or is there any other way or I have to code myself ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this question has 4 years old at the moment I'm writing this answer, but this question deserves an answer.

**My opinion**

> *Is django-oscar-accounts the right app for that ? Or is there any other way or I have to code myself ?*

Yes, surely it is, you can, of course, implement the solution your self, but `django-oscar-accounts` has this (and others) features already implemented.

Oscar framework is designed in a way that the payment flow is up to the developer, so, go ahead and give a try to `django-oscar-accounts`. Is a very good app!